# cut command fields

Tags: awk, grep, cut, command-substitution, uniq

I noticed these two different fields behaviors using `cut` command:

```
bash:~$ var=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6,7,8 `  
echo $var
```

outputs

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
```

and:

```
bash:~$ echo `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq` | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6,7,8
```

outputs

```
: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @
```

fields numbers are the same but different outputs. Why?

Answer (score 9):

It is because the unquoted `` backquote command substitution has removed an extra space between the `model name` and the `:` characters. Refer to the outputs without the `grep` to see the difference for yourself

```
echo `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq`
model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

and with

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
#         ^^ - 2 spaces rather than one
```

As a result the `cut` sees different fields from number `3` onwards in both the cases. This can be fixed if you avoid using backticks and use `$(..)` with a proper quoted substitution

```
echo "$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq)" | cut -d ' ' -f 3,4,5,6,7,8
```

---

But that said, using `cat`/`grep` etc sequentially can be avoided and a single `awk` can be used in-place of it

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ "model name" { print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Or even more exact, if a single leading space in the above result is worrisome, remove it using `sub`

```
awk -F: '$1 ~ "model name" { sub(/^[[:space:]]/ ,"" , $2); print $2 }' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Or if you have `GNU` variant of `grep` which has PCRE regex enabled, which you can use as

```
grep -oP 'model name(\s+):(\s+)\K(.+)' /proc/cpuinfo
```